# SQL получить строки без русских букв

Tags: sql

Хочу получить все строки без русских букв в определенном поле. Делаю запрос:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `dle_post` WHERE `full_story` not like '%[а-я]%'
```

Выводит все строки - как с русскими буквами, так и без них.
В чем моя ошибка? Как вывести все строки без русских букв?

Попробовал без диапазона или набора, например `%а%`- работает. Какие проблемы могут быть с диапазоном/набором?

Примеры везде с символами `[]%_^` - [Оператор SQL LIKE](http://2sql.ru/novosti/sql-like/). Может, есть альтернативное решение - без регулярок? Или `[а-я]%` - это последовательность, а `%[а-я]%` - уже регулярка, так как алгоритму нужно несколько раз проходить по строке, чтобы найти совпадения?

Comment: Попробовал без диапазона или набора(напр. '%а%')- работает. Какие проблемы могут быть с диапазоном/набором ?

Comment: @Drakonoved Гуглю- примеры везде с символами []%_^ напр. http://2sql.ru/novosti/sql-like/  Может подскажите альтернативное решение- без регулярок? Или вы к тому, что например [а-я]% это последовательность, а %[а-я]% уже регулярка, так как алгоритму нужно несколько раз проходить по строке, что бы найти  совпадения?

Comment: LIKE не поддерживает требуемый тип шаблонов. Используйте NOT REGEXP https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: @Akina Благодарю  SELECT * FROM dle_post WHERE full_story NOT REGEXP '[а-я]'   работает.